# How to install and activate a plugin using an external PHP script?

Tags: plugins, php, deployment

I'm using a custom Php script to install WordPress via the Softaculous API. Once installed, what's the best way to programmatically install and activate a plugin? I could try setting up a custom WP script in Softaculous with a PHP script in a custom plugin in an mu-plugins folder, but I would prefer not to do that, and instead install/activate the plugin after the WP installation.

So what I would like to do after the WP main install and from an external PHP script if possible is:

1. authenticate with admin credentials via PHP
2. download a specific plugin from the repository
3. install the
   plugin
4. activate the plugin

Maybe I could use the `TGM-Plugin-Activation` to install/activate another plugin, but I would need to be able to install/activate that plugin itself. Is this possible without any admin user clicks and without using the mu-plugins folder pre-install?

I've read these posts:

[Activating a single plugin via php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/269613/activating-a-single-plugin-via-php)

[Plugin to install a plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117459/plugin-to-install-a-plugin)

Comment: Why not use [WP CLI](http://wp-cli.org/) to [install, active the plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/plugin/)?

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179963/install-an-external-plugin-within-the-current-plugin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## WP CLI

The easy way; use the [WP CLI](http://wp-cli.org/) (also available as `wp-cli.phar`) to get a solid, maintainable solution for this requirement. More for this topic you will find at the command

- [`wp plugin <command>`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/plugin/)

---

## WP API

If you will need a custom script is is necessary to load the WP API, via `wp-load.php` and look for the function `activate_plugin($path_to_the_plugin)`.

### Activation

As example what you need to get all requirements to activate a plugin see below

```
define( 'WP_ADMIN', TRUE );
define( 'WP_NETWORK_ADMIN', TRUE ); // Need for Multisite
define( 'WP_USER_ADMIN', TRUE );

require_once('../wp-load.php');
require_once( '../wp-admin/includes/admin.php' );
require_once( '../wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );

activate_plugin( 'PATH_TO_THE_PLUGIN' );
```

### Installation

The installation of a plugin is also possible via the API of WP, also code thats should helps a little bit to run in the right direction.

```
// Include required libs for installation
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin-install.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-ajax-upgrader-skin.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-plugin-upgrader.php' );

// Get Plugin Info
$api = plugins_api( 'plugin_information',
    array(
        'slug' => $plugin,
        'fields' => array(
            'short_description' => false,
            'sections' => false,
            'requires' => false,
            'rating' => false,
            'ratings' => false,
            'downloaded' => false,
            'last_updated' => false,
            'added' => false,
            'tags' => false,
            'compatibility' => false,
            'homepage' => false,
            'donate_link' => false,
        ),
    )
);
$skin     = new WP_Ajax_Upgrader_Skin();
$upgrader = new Plugin_Upgrader( $skin );
$upgrader->install( $api->download_link );
```

A example that install and activate see you in [this class](https://github.com/dcooney/wordpress-plugin-installer/blob/master/class-connekt-plugin-installer.php).

Comment: I don't want to use the command line, I want to run from a Php script. I will experiment with your code above and see if I can adapt the connekt class. Many thanks for this info!

Comment: However you can also use the WP CLI possibilities via script, download the `wp-cli.phar` fro the WP CLI project and usage in your script.

Comment: Thank you muchly for your updates. To use wp-cli from Php I believe would require using the shell_exec command which I've disabled on the server for security reasons. I'm going to test the API option ...